# Set GPU as render device when using Net Render

Tags: gpu, network

I have setup my master and slave blender servers following steps 1 through 16 on this [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341555-How-to-set-up-a-netrender-on-the-GPU).

I can send jobs to the networked system and it renders but I can not, despite trying a great many things, get the network system with a GTX 970 to render the job using CUDA compute.

If someone with experience in this could give some insight and/or suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Follow the instructions to install this Plugin, and it'll add GPU compute capability. [https://github.com/WARP-LAB/Blender-Network-Render-Additions](https://github.com/WARP-LAB/Blender-Network-Render-Additions)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. There was a 3rd party fork of the network renderer plugin that did it although it's been abandoned now.